# Show that the Cauchy integral formula implies the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analyticity

I'm struggling with this question, the integral formula states:

$$f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz$$

and the Cauchy-Goursat theorem states:

If $f$ is holomorphic in a simply connected domain $D$ and $C$ contained in $D$ is a closed curve, then $\int_{C}f(z)\,dz =0$

To be perfectly honest I'm not at all sure where to start with question.

Comment: I believe you need Cauchy's Integral theorem to prove the integral formula?

Comment: Hint : apply Cauchy's formula to the function $g(z)=(z-z_0) f(z)$.

Comment: Can you show the integral formula implies the theorem?

Answer (score 4):

Let $z_0$ in the interior of $C$ and $g(z)=(z-z_0)f(z)$. Then Cauchy Integral Formula provides

$$
0=g(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c}\frac{g(z)}{z-z_0}\,dz= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c}\frac{f(z)(z-z_0)}{z-z_0}\,dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c}f(z)\,dz.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: what if you take $g(z) = (z - z_0) f(z)$?

By the way, your integral formula has a missing $i$.

Comment: I feel like a complete idiot, this is so simple, thank you Robert.